# Why are there static and non static overloads of Equals in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, equals

Why are there [two overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5171fyh.aspx) of `Equals` in .NET's object class? If I want to have a custom equality function, e.g. so that I can use sets or dictionaries, should I override both (in addition to `GetHashCode`), or it is enough to override just one of them.

Comment: You cant override a static method?!

Comment: @Jamiec That's right, I can't.. this is embarassing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't override the static version.

The reason for the static version is so that you can call `object.Equals(myObject, myOtherObject)` without checking for nulls beforehand.

Internally, it just checks for nulls (returning `true` if both objects are null), then delegates to `myObject.Equals(myOtherObject)`. So overriding the non-static Equals method is all you need.

Comment: I see.. I guess implementations of sets, dictionaries, etc will call the static method?

Comment: If they're not implemented by newbie coders, yes. Otherwise they'll probably reinvent the wheel and do their own null checking before calling the non-static version.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override a static method.

Override only the non static method and it'll be fine...

Read this article: 
[How to: override static methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2008/02/06/how-to-override-static-methods.aspx):

> **Why can't we override static members?**
>
> Really, why? If you think about it, this is just common sense.
>   Overriding usual (instance) members uses the virtual dispatch
>   mechanism to separate the contract from the implementation. The
>   contract is known at compile time (instance member signature), but the
>   implementation is only known at runtime (concrete type of object
>   provides a concrete implementation). You don't know the concrete type
>   of the implementation at compile time.
>
> This is an important thing to understand: when types inherit from
>   other types, they fulfil a common contract, whereas static types are
>   not bound by any contract (from the pure OOP point of view). There's
>   no technical way in the language to tie two static types together with
>   an "inheritance" contract. If you would "override" the Log method in
>   two different places, how do we know which one we are calling here:
>   Log.Message("what is the implementation?")
>
> With static members, you call them by explicitly specifying the type
>   on which they are defined. Which means, you directly call the
>   implementation, which, again, is not bound to any contract.
>
> By the way, that's why static members can't implement interfaces. And
>   that's why virtual dispatch is useless here - all clients directly
>   call the implementation, without any contract.

Answer (score 2):

The static method exists in case the "first" object is null. For example, if `a` is null and `b` is not null, you will not be able to run `a.Equals(b)` but you will be able to run `object.Equals(a, b)`.

You should (and **can**) override only the instance method, for two reasons. First, you cannot override the static method. Second, the static method will eventually call the non-static method.

For more info, please refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx).